# C++: Segmentation fault in one stack code, not in the other version

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

- code A:

```
#include<iostream>

class node{
    private:
        node* nxt;
    public:
        node(){}
        void push();
};

void node::push(){
    node* newNode = new node();
    this->nxt = newNode;
}

int main(){
    node hello;
    hello.push();
}
```

- code B:

```
#include<iostream>

class node{
    private:
        node* nxt;
    public:
        node(){}
        void push();
};

void node::push(){
    node* newNode = new node();
    this->nxt = newNode;
}

int main(){
    node* hello;
    hello->push();
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting segmentation fault while running code B,
Whereas Code A executes without any issue.

And what's the right way to execute code B without any issue?

Comment: `node* hello;` is an unitialized pointer. You need to make it point to something.

Comment: In code B, you need to create a `node` object for `hello` to point at, eg: `node* hello = new node; ... delete hello;` or `node n; node* hello = &n;` Also note that in BOTH codes, `node::nxt` is also uninitialized, so if you ever try to iterate through the list, you will likely try to reach past the last node in the list and run into new problems.

Comment: This is really a question about why a segfault happens, not comparing the two code options you have. Clearly the difference in your code is just the one line where in one case it is a pointer to the object.

Comment: *"what's the right way to execute code B without any issue?"* -- changing it to match code A is one way. Is that too obvious? *(Maybe I would be more understanding if you had written out a description of how the code differs instead of expecting me to do a line-by-line comparison. Needlessly piling work onto volunteers tends to sap their willingness.)*

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because there are no comments in your code. It's not clear what you think `node* hello;` does or what you think `hello->push();` does. So it's not clear what the code is supposed to do. You ask us how to do whatever it is that code is trying to do, but don't tell us what it's trying to do. So how can we answer? You have code A already which does something. If that's what code B is supposed to do, what's the question? You already know how to do ... something.

Answer (score 0):

In code B, hello node pointer wasn't pointing to any address (segmentation fault) because i didn't initialized it.

instead of

```
node* hello;
```

it should have been

```
node* hello = new node();
```